# How to find marks between 50 to 100 using mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb

```
db.mycollection.find([{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        city: 1,
        "Marks": { $range: [ 50, "$marks", 100] }
    }
}])
```

Comment: what is the type for `Marks` field?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$range` in `aggregate`

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        city: 1,
        "Marks range": { $range: [ 50, "$marks", 100 ] }
    }
}])
```

reference link : [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/)

Or You can use `find`

```
db.mycollection.find({ marks: { $gte:50, $lt: 100 } })
```

Comment: For OP, have a look at the difference between `$gte`, `$gt`, `$lt` and `$lte`